# Sitecore 7 WFFM Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.0.0

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7

I'm upgrading a website from Sitecore 6.5 to Sitecore 7. The upgrade has been smooth and I was able to get everything up and running except for WFFM.

After installing WFFM 2.3 latest, I keep getting the error

> Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Sitecore 7 upgrades it's 3rd party dll for HtmlAgilityPack to 1.4.3, but WFFM seems to still reference 1.4.0

Has anyone dealt with this? Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug for Sitecore. Check out [this link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,3/Release%20Notes/Known%20issues.aspx) for a fix (382886).

Comment: Thank you. That web.config change fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into HtmlAgilityPack version mismatches during previous Sitecore upgrades when WFFM was installed. I've just been able to update the reference by hand to the new file without suffering any consequences.

It seems that a separate team works on WFFM and the work is lagged several months behind the Sitecore core.

Comment: Thanks Matt. My problem is actually not finding that reference. Any pointers?

Comment: Hmmmm, do you have an HtmlAgilityPack.dll in your /website/bin folder? If it didn't get copied over correctly by the upgrade package, you can probably find it within the folders inside the .zip of the package itself and put it there by hand. it's also an open source project by itself and you can get it here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925